# Unable to checkout specific commit file

Tags: git

With this command `git show 51eec182 path/to/filename`

```
commit 51eec182c258b4525f0ba3a6303e3be349789f54
Author: Android <Android@MobileDEV>
Date:   Tue May 2 09:06:48 2017 +0700

    add methods to models

.....
.....
-this line is removed
+this line is added
.....
.....
```

What I want is "this line is removed" is back

so I run this command

`git checkout 51eec182 -- path/to/filename`

But the "this line is removed" not back.

Anyway previously I run `git reset HEAD path/to/filename`

Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `git checkout 51eec182^ -- path/to/filename`

Comment: Answer it please, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file's content is `this line is added` in the commit `51eec182c`. `this line is removed` is in the commit previous of `51eec182`. The previous commit is the parent of `51eec182`. Since `51eec182` is not a merge-commit, it has only one parent. We can refer to this first parent by adding the symbol "^" right behind the commit hash, `51eec182^`.

So `git checkout 51eec182^ -- path/to/filename`.